# Use of v_ in SetProperty for. graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching

I found the following code (I forgot to mark the link--it was on the topic of displaying two values at a graph vertex):

```
graph4 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2}, VertexWeight -> {102, 103, 104}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];

SetProperty[graph4, {VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[{"Name", 
  AnnotationValue[{graph4, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}]}, 
  ImagePadding -> 20}]
```

The question regards the meaning of v_ in the SetProperty part of the code. I understand the use of v_ in a function definition, say Sum[x_,y_] := x + y. I chased up SetProperty in Wolfram online documentation, but did not encounter this use of v_

Comment: It is a rule, look it up in the manual. Rules are used e.g. for replacements.

Comment: Thanks will check it

Comment: @Daniel, more accurately, the `v_` part is a *pattern*; it's the `:>` that's a `Rule`(`Delayed`).

Comment: Yes, I found the pattern reference. I still surprises me that it is used in this context. I am not sure why VertexLabels -> {v  :> Placed[{"Name", 
  AnnotationValue[{graph4, v}, VertexWeight]}, {Above, Below}]}, 
  ImagePadding -> 20}] would not work (simply using v rather than v_). I can see the use of patterns in arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that makes `v_` a pattern is the `_`, which matches any single expression by itself. Indeed, `f[_] := expr` is sometimes seen, and `f` will return `expr` regardless of input. `v_` is just a way of naming the thing that `_` matches, so you can keep track of it on the right hand side of `:>` or `:=`!

`v`, on the other hand, is a literal pattern that only matches the actual symbol/variable name `v` (well, as long as v is undefined; otherwise the variable evaluates to whatever is stored in it.)

On the right-hand-side of the `:>` or `:=`, the lone `v` there actually refers to the name of the pattern on the left hand side, and is not a pattern itself. It's sort of a local variable at that point.

In general, `x : patt` is a way to name an arbitrary pattern `patt`, and `x_` is essentially syntactic sugar for `x : _`. Likewise, `x__` and `x___` are similar shorthands, for a sequence of one or more expressions and a sequence of zero or more expressions respectively. `x_head` is shorthand for a pattern named `x` which has head `head` (e.g. `x_List` matches a single list), and `x_?f` is shorthand for a pattern which matches any expression `expr` for which `f[expr]` is `True`. These are the main pattern shorthands I can think of.

Check out [this documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html), [this doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) and [this doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html) for more info on how patterns are used, especially in `:>` and `:=`.